# Multiple correct question based on permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I try to solve this the number of permutation in $S_{n}$ for $n\geq 4$ which are product of two disjoint $2$-cycles is $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{8}$.
So after putting $n=5$ and $n=4$ I get different answer. Am I right ?
Please help how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh thanks@Morgan

Comment: @Morgan how to solve this ?

Comment: @MorganRodgers That's not right, for $a_4$ you also have a product of a $3$-cycle and a $1$-cycle. In fact there are $8$ of these, and $3$ products of $2$ $2$-cycles.

Comment: @derek holt you get correct answer for $a_4$

Comment: But how you did it please explain.

Comment: @Derek how about the product 1-cycle and 1-cycle or 1-cycle and 2-cycle

Comment: @MusaddiqueKhan Yes, $a_4=11$ and $a_5=50$, but you can do the calcualtion yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ambiguity in the question. If an element remains fixed, does that count as a 1-cycle?

If we assume it does, then for $n=4$ the only possibilities are type $(12)(34)$ (3 possibilities) or type $(123)(4)$ (8 possibilities, 4 ways of choosing the 1-cycle, then 2 ways of choosing the 3-cycle). So we get $a_4=11$.

For $n=5$ the only possibilities are type $(123)(45)$ (10 ways of choosing the elements in the 3-cycle, then 2 possibilities for each choice, total 20), or type $(1234)(5)$ (5 ways of choosing the 1-cycle, then 6 ways of ordering the elements in the 4-cycle). So $a_5=50$.

If we don't count 1-cycles, then:

For $n=4$ the only possibilities are $(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)$. So $a_4=3$.

For $n=5$ the only possibilities are type $(123)(45)$ and type $(12)(34)$. The first has 20 possibilities (10 ways of choosing the elements in the 3-cycle and 2 possibilities for each choice). The second has 15 possibilities (5 ways of choosing which element remains fixed, then 3 $a_4$ possibilities). Hence $a_5=35$.

Presumably we are meant to adopt the first interpretation (count 1-cycles).

Comment: I don't think there is any ambiguity. People are just not reading it carefully. The two possibilities for $n=5$ are a product of a $3$-cycle and a $2$-cycle, and the product of a $4$-cycle and a $1$-cycle. I get $a_5=50$.